# How do I float arrows and bullet points inline for JQUERY content slider with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Need help aligning some elements in css. Currently have a small content slider that will display simple lists, like news posts etc. Everything runs fine, I just need help aligning the arrows and pagination points. I'd like the bullet points in the middle of each arrow.

[This is what it currently looks like](http://www.garyrevell.co.uk/screenshot_01.jpg)

Live WIP link -> http://www.garyrevell.co.uk/mrtest/index.html

---

This is my HTML + CSS

```
 <!--START DEALS-->

 <div class="box-deals">

 <h1> Latest Deals </h1>
<hr>

    <article>

    <div id="slider1">
                                            <div class="viewport">
                        <ul class="overview">

                            <li>

                            <div class="dealimg"><img src="images/blank-logo.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="feature-img"></div>

                            <div class="dealtitle">Deal Title Here</div>

                            <div class="deal-des">Mon - Thur, Sat only specific text here</div>

                            <p> <a href="#">Login</a> or <a href="#">signup</a> to get this deal </p>


</li>

<li>

                            <div class="dealimg"><img src="images/blank-logo.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="feature-img"></div>

                            <div class="dealtitle">Deal Title Here</div>

                            <div class="deal-des">Mon - Thur, Sat only specific text here</div>

                            <p> <a href="#">Login</a> or <a href="#">signup</a> to get this deal </p>


</li>




                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <a class="buttons prev" href="#">left</a>

                    <a class="buttons next" href="#">right</a>

                    <ul class="pager">
                        <li><a rel="0" href="#" class="pagenum active">1</a></li>
                        <li><a rel="1" href="#" class="pagenum">2</a></li>

                    </ul>





                </div>  


    </article>




</div><!--END DEALS-->
```

This is my CSS

```
/* Slider-Bullets*/

#slider1 .pager { overflow:hidden; list-style: none; clear: both; margin: 0 0 0 45px; }

/*Normal Style*/

#slider1 .pager li { float: left;  display: block; 

}

#slider1 .pager a { width: 15px;
height: 15px;
background:url(../images/bullet-norm.png); background-position: left top; background-repeat:no-repeat;
float: left;
text-indent: -4000px;
position: relative;
margin-left: 3px;
color: transparent;
display:inline;
clear: left;




}

#slider1 .pager a:hover{
    background-position: 0 50%;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    float: left; 
    text-indent: -4000px; 
    position:relative;
    margin-left:3px;

    color:transparent;
}

/*Active Style*/

#slider1 .pager .active { color: #fff; background-image:url(../images/bullet-selected.png); } /*CURRENT IMAGE HERE*/
#slider1 .overview { list-style: none; position: absolute; width: 240px; left: 0 top: 0; }
#slider1 .overview li{ float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 0;  width: 236px;


}

/* Tiny Carousel */
#slider1 { height: 1%; overflow:hidden; padding: 0 0 10px;   }

#slider1 .viewport { float: left; width: 240px; min-height: 190px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }

#slider1 .buttons { background:url("../images/buttons.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; display: block; margin: 30px 10px 0 0; background-position: 0 -38px; text-indent: -999em; float: left; width: 39px; height: 37px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }

#slider1 .previous { background-position: 0 0; margin-left:5px;  }
#slider1 .next { background-position: 0 0; left: 130px }
#slider1 .disable { visibility: hidden; }

#slider1 .overview { list-style: none; position: absolute; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 240px; left: 0 top: 0; }
#slider1 .overview li{ float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 0; padding: 1px; height: 121px;  width: 230px;}
```

Thankyou in advance.

Gary

Comment: Do you have a live url to analyze it?

Comment: Yes certainly. http://www.garyrevell.co.uk/mrtest/index.html

Comment: Given a solution in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

in your `style.css` you need to change following:

- on line **562** i.e. `#slider1 .buttons` give negative `top-margin` like given below:

  `margin: -10px 10px 0 0`
- on line **616** i.e. `#slider1 .pager` Remove `clear:both`

Then your slider will behave normally.

Comment: Thankyou for the help. When I follow above it results in the bullet points vanashing. I require this result -> http://www.garyrevell.co.uk/screenshot_02.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="test">
    <a class="buttons prev" href="#">left</a> 
    <ul class="pager">
        <li><a rel="0" href="#" class="pagenum active">1</a></li> 
        <li><a rel="1" href="#" class="pagenum">2</a></li> 
    </ul>
    <a class="buttons next" href="#">right</a> 
</div>
```